# What is this compiler error with generics

Tags: c#, generics

I am getting this compiler error:

> The type `'Generics.Widget'` cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method `'Generics.MyGenerics.Maximum<T>(T, T, T)'`. There is no implicit reference conversion from `'Generics.Widget'` to `'System.IComparable<Generics.Widget>'`

See the attached screen shot for the compiler error in code that is trying to use this class.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Generics {
        // A class that implements IComparable
        class Widget : System.IComparable {
            private String name;

            public Widget(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            int System.IComparable.CompareTo(object obj) {
                return name.CompareTo(((Widget)obj).name);
            } 
        }
    }
```

[image: Screen Shot of compiler error]

Comment: Show the actual/relevant code.

Comment: I expected downvotes but I think people are too harsh...It's not the worst question we've seen.Yes ,OP could have posted the Maximum method but    the error refers to the Class and the relevant code was shown...

Comment: @GeorgeVovos  I expected no downvotes. I always overestimate SO denizens.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the generic version of  IComparable

```
public interface IComparable<in T>


class Widget : System.IComparable<Widget>
{
    public int CompareTo(Widget other)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }    
}
```

You haven't shown your Maximum method but obviously it has a constraint on T

```
where T : IComparable<Widget>
```